# R- key in data in data.frame when don't know row number

Tags: r, dataframe

If there is a data.frame names 'DF',how can I enter 'yellow' when I don't know the row number,thanks.

from

```
     fruit  year  color
?    apple  2017  red
?    apple  2018  red
?    apple  2019  red
?    banana 2017 
?    banana 2018
?    banana 2019
?    orange 2017  orange
?    orange 2018  orange
?    orange 2019  orange
```

to

```
     fruit  year  color
?    apple  2017  red
?    apple  2018  red
?    apple  2019  red
?    banana 2017  yellow
?    banana 2018  yellow
?    banana 2019  yellow
?    orange 2017  orange
?    orange 2018  orange
?    orange 2019  orange
```

Comment: clarified, thanks.

Comment: `DF$color <- ifelse(trimws(DF$color) == "", "yellow", DF$color)`.

Comment: thanks, I'm curious if the color of the apple is empty too, how can I do it?

Comment: How does one know that "banana" is "yellow", "apple" is "red" ? Is it stored somewhere ?

Comment: Let me think.... , If there is a data.frame like 'color of fruit' ,Will it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to create a look-up dataframe and then `match` based on `fruit`

```
color_fruit <- data.frame(fruit = c('apple', 'banana', 'orange'), 
              color = c('red', 'yellow', 'orange'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$color <- color_fruit$color[match(df$fruit, color_fruit$fruit)]
df

#   fruit year  color
#1  apple 2017    red
#2  apple 2018    red
#3  apple 2019    red
#4 banana 2017 yellow
#5 banana 2018 yellow
#6 banana 2019 yellow
#7 orange 2017 orange
#8 orange 2018 orange
#9 orange 2019 orange
```

Or we can also join

```
merge(df, color_fruit, by = 'fruit')[-3]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(fruit = c("apple", "apple", "apple", "banana", 
"banana", "banana", "orange", "orange", "orange"), year = c(2017L, 
2018L, 2019L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L), color = c("red", 
"red", "red", "", "", "", "orange", "orange", "orange")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: thanks,I'll try it later.